# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'

Tags: python, buildozer

Скомпилировал apk файл, без ошибок, но при запуске на смартфоне - вылетает. Через logcat вывел ошибку (ниже лог). Читал все похожие темы и пробовал применить решения, но они не помогли. Компиляцию проделывал через PyCharm, файл `_bz2.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` тыкал уже везде, и по пути python (как указано ниже), и по пути созданой виртуальной среды `/venv/и_дальше`, и по пути компиляции buildozer
`/.buildozer/и_дальше`

Versions

```
Python: 3.10.6
OS: linux
Buildozer:1.5.0
```

Description

```
installed `libbz2-dev` version `1.0.8-5build1`
done: `sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/`
Did not help.
```

Logs

```
File "/home/odinson/PycharmProjects/FindImageDescription/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/bz2.py", line 17, in <module>
09-18 13:18:43.959  6117  6162 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код.

Comment: @wchistow код проекта или скрипта в котором ошибка? Он указывает на импорт библиотеки, которая якобы не установлена, хотя если я буду объявлять ее в проекте, то все ок.